# How to correctly decouple SAML logic from Service Provider into its own authentication microservice

Tags: authentication, microservices, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to implement SSO with SAML 2.0 in a dynamic web app whose frontend and backend-for-frontend are outsourced and hence not maintained by my company. At the same time, this dashboard is to be used by external organizations so federation with SAML 2.0 is a requirement.

I've been reading a lot on SAML integrations but the vast majority of them involve making changes in the Service Provider itself (in other words, the web app) but, as I mentioned earlier, doing this would require making many changes in the outsourced codebase which – for business reasons – is a no go.

To avoid this, I would like to have an authentication service to handle as much SAML logic as possible. This way, we would be able to easily scale on the amount of identity providers and even SSO protocols in the future while minimizing the modifications on the frontends.

[Find sketched sequence diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK7q5.png)

After sketching the sequence diagram up, I realized I don't quite understand a few things yet:

1. Is the Service Provider receiving meaningful cookies once the Identity Provider successfully authenticates the user? If so, would it be wise to use them from the Service Provider and the Authentication Service to determine whether the user is authenticated or not?
2. If not, then the only possible way for a Service Provider to know whether a federated session is already established or not is to ask the Identity Provider every time, on each request it receives to a protected resource, right? Wouldn't this delay each request's response time too much?

Thank you!

Comment: I did something like this with a central SAML Engine (a spring boot app) and satellite apps that needed SAML integration but didn't want to deal with SAML. They redirected the browser to the SAML Engine which did all the SAML flows and processing and sent the SAML XML attributes as JSON to the requesting satellite app. The SAML Engine was registered as the "SP" in the federation metadata but it was working on behalf of the satellite apps. Cookies don't come into it at the SAML Engine, only the SAML Response which was parsed and sent as JSON back to the satellite app.